# Aggregation with Mongodb c# Driver 2.4 not working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-csharp-2.0

When using the commands as below, it returning null.

```
        var pipeline = new BsonDocument[] {
            new BsonDocument{{"$group", new BsonDocument{{"_id", "$BrandId"}}}}
        };

        var brands = context
            .Items.Aggregate<BsonDocument>(pipeline);
```

[image]

Data ex:

[image]

The Aggregation method I have as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that all you are missing is doing a ToList() or ToListAsync() after the `Aggregate()` call to make it return the data.

Is there a reason you are not using the Group method instead?

```
Aggregate().Group(new BsonDocument() { "_id" : "$BrandId"})
```

Comment: I only have one method Aggregate<T>(BsonDocument).

I don't see Aggragate().Group(BsonDocument)

Comment: @GSH It's definitely there, we are using it and it's in the docs https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/csharp/aggregation/. As I said all you seemed to be missing was the ToList() call and it worked fine for me. Hard to comment any further without seeing more code.

Comment: I was missing MongoDB.Driver.Linq namespace.